# Oracle to H2/hsqldb etc adapter

Tags: java, sql, oracle, maven, h2

I can't be the only person who has this problem so I am looking for suggestions.

We run our apps on Oracle but our integration tests use h2 for speedy in-memory testing, the database being built from DDL scripts at the start of testing.

The problem is that the use/syntax of some DDL commands differs between Oracle and h2/hsqldb. For example today I spent some time before I realised that 'grant select on ...' works on sequences in Oracle but only on tables in h2.

In a previous project we had an adapter to remove/translate such erroneous commands, which meant that our test database ran quite different code to that we implement to prod. While everything is very thoroughly acceptance tested it means that certain problems might not be spotted until quite late on in the dev cycle.

On my latest project I sense I am going down the same path - so surely others must also have trodden it.

Any suggestions? We're using java/maven so appropriate soutions welcome!

Comment: Did you get a chance to introduce an ORM (like Hibernate) to abstract out these differences? We also have similar setup of Oracle in test stage and HSQLDB in unit-test stage and ORM worked well so far.

Comment: This is a use of the term "integration testing" with which I have not been heretofore familiar.  In my experience integration testing is the point at which you test the new software in an environment which mirrors, to the maximum extent possible, the production target.  IMO using a completely different database "for speedy in-memory testing" is false economy.

Comment: @BobJarvis - I refer to the tests as integration tests as the purists among us (of which I am not one I might add) don't like to refer to these as unit tests. All the same, small scale tests that run quickly during the build cycle and exercise the database are very useful - if Oracle had a cheap/free in-memory database I would use that, but they don't so this is the path that we take. A full integration test (we call it system integration) would, of course, use the production target database.

Comment: @DaveRlz Why don't you just install Oracle XE and mount it on a ramfs partition? This would be the closest you would get to a free in-memory DB from Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't such an adapter to my knowledge.

Anyway, I'd say that you're not going to achieve your goals with such an adapter. For one, the feature set of Oracle is not easily found in any other solution ( not that that's necessarily an advantage for Oracle).

Comment: I agree that the features are not comparable, what I didn't mention is that I am not bothered about any 'advanced' features (i.e stored procs, database links, interesting table structures etc) but just relatively common stuff table definitions/constraints/indexes, data types, permissions etc.

Comment: @DaveRlz I think that your best bet is to find an abstraction for that. For instance, for DDLs you can use Liquibase to create DB-independent DDL statements. Or Hibernate as an ORM .